# Excel hangs when trying to save a shared file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a fairly large spreadsheet (~ 5MB) shared between several users. While some users have no problems, some see Excel hang when they try to save their changes. It can happen when they are the only ones using the file, or in a shared situation (in which case they block everyone else). All have the same PC configuration.

Any clue or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem a few years ago. We shared an Excel (with macro's) with about 6 people. It was horrible ... Nothing much you can do about it. You can check some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670865/excel-workbook-is-slow-and-crashes-a-lot)

Comment: [This post](http://superuser.com/a/586321/150988) (by a [reputable user](http://superuser.com/users/107753/teylyn "teylyn")) says, "Sharing Excel workbooks only leads to trouble, because it's a question of ***when*** not ***if*** the shared file becomes corrupt and unusable."

Comment: After sharing an Excel spreadsheet for a while, it becomes confused has to who actually still has the workbook open.  I have found that unsharing the workbook, saving it, then resharing it again usually worked.  I believe, though don't know with absolute certainty, that this happens when people close Windows without first closing a shared workbook.  I suspect this because I always close all apps before shutting down Windows, and I have never seen my ID twice in Excel's shared list.

Comment: To add to BillOers comment, you can open the sharing screen and kick users that aren't actually inside the document. I guess it's the same thing, just a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here I was in a similar situation and it is most likely caused from excel thinking users are logged in when they are not and tons of custom views being saved in the file my script clears all that out.

[How do you prevent corruption of shared Excel files?](https://superuser.com/questions/961918/how-do-you-prevent-corruption-of-shared-excel-files)